# Chemical formula and heat

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, heat

In my Physical Science class, we are learning about chemical formulas and how to balance them. I balanced this equation:

$$
\ce{Fe2O3 + Al -> Fe + Al2O3}
$$

One of the other students asked me if this chemical formula releases or absorbs heat.

Could anyone help me give a great explanation for this question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminothermic_reaction

Comment: Check $\Delta H$ tables and calculate if the reaction is **endothermic** or **exothermic**.

Comment: @Sydney U:  Please note currently (22:10 UTC time), your reaction equation is *not* yet balanced correctly.

Comment: Look up *thermite* for more information on this displacement reaction. My students enjoyed seeing it demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve this problem is to look at the $\Delta H$ charts found online. Using the simple equation below will give you the answer.

> $$\sum \Delta H_{\text{Products}} - \sum \Delta H_\text{Reactants} = \Delta H_{\text{Reaction}}$$
>   If the $\Delta H$ is positive in sign then the reaction is **endothermic** and if it is negative in sign then it is **exothermic**.